# Microsoft Graph API *error* when querying AuditLog using Python

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I wrote a script to see when a set of users last logged in. I use this query:

```
request_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=contains(UserPrincipalName,'{userPrincipalName}')&$orderby=createdDateTime desc&$top=1"
```

I have two accounts, both contain "xt_laro", so this code will fetch my last sign-in from the AuditLogs.

It seems to work fine when I only make one query. But I put my code into a loop, and then I noticed that it begins to return incorrect data.

For example: I ran the request for the same six users 5 times in a row. The first time, it said that my last sign-in was yesterday. The next time, it said that my last sign-in was today, and the third time, it says that my last sign-in was 2 days ago. In other words. **Microsoft Graph API seems to return inconsistent data**.

If I add a 3 second delay between each iteration of the loop `sleep(3)` then I get the correct response (my last sign-in is today).

Why does this happen?
How can I ensure that my query fetches the LAST sign-in attempt and not a random sign-in attempt from the last week?

*Additional information:*
I tried to loop through the last 30 days and fetch ALL sign-in attempts for the same 6 users. If I include `sleep(3)` after my request, then I get a full list of data. But if I remove this delay, then **there are blank lines in my output**!

*EDIT/RESPONSE:*
Due to the number of requests, **I got subjected to throttling** (look it up). Some replies have a "Retry-After" element. It shows how long I must wait before I try again. I wait by adding the line: `time.sleep(3)`
This makes Python wait 3 seconds before trying again.
In the end, I had to read the Retry-After and sleep for that long.

Comment: The API is working fine when we checked in graph explorer , I  understood you face the issue when looping for 6 different user , could you please provide us the code to check what's going wrong  . secondly ,I would like to understand when you used the sleep time 3 millisecond , are you getting the correct data for all users ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem, thank you for your answers though.

It turns out that I was losing data because of "throttling" in Microsoft Graph API. Some queries simply returned blank for last_login.

To resolve it, I now scan every response header for the keys 'error' and 'Retry-after'. Then I politely sleep that amount of seconds and re-send the request. Sometimes I have to wait 3 times before I get the response.

I also had to scan the header for errors regarding invalid Authentication Token because it expires after 1 hour and my script was still running.

By the way: time.sleep(3) = 3 seconds in Python 3.